# How to update an array using setState with React Hooks on Strict Mode

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this, every time **addEmail** is called, the updater callback for **setEmails** is called twice and therefore the new email is added twice:

```
const Container = (props: Props) => {
const [emails, setEmails] = useState<Array<string>>([]);

const addEmail = (email: string) => {

    setEmails((prevState: string[]) => [...prevState, email]);
};

return (
    <Wrapper>
        {emails.map((email, index) => {
            return (
                <Email
                    key={index}
                    text={email}
                    onRemoveClicked={() => {}}
                />
            );
        })}
        <Input onSubmit={addEmail} />
    </Wrapper>
);
```

};

How am i supposed to do this on strict mode ?

Comment: You are going to need to post some more code on how you call addEmails. strict mode does not call hooks twice like that

Comment: @topched6 just updated the code

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a lot more context here, This component doesn't look like a native html `form`. `Email` and `Input` both are custom components.

I would suggest you to try the below steps to debug this

1. Check if `Input` component is calling `onSubmit` twice.
2. React's useState setter method takes the new state as argument, you are passing a function here, that might be the problem. Try changing the `addEmail` function definition to below and see if it works

   ```js
   const addEmail = (newEmail: string) => setEmails([...emails, newEmail]);
   ```

Read More about [React state hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Comment: The onSubmit is not being called twice, what is is being called twice is the callback on setEmails.